# Razor: Calling helper method on click

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm writing a wep application in which I'm using the Razor syntax here and there. (It's build on the CMS Umbraco).

What I want to do is to call a method when a link (or button or whatever) is clicked. Something like this:

```
<a id="anchorId" class="AnchorClass" href="#" 
onclick="@ClassName.Methodname(var1 v, var2 v)">
LinkText</a>
```

Problem is that Razor wants to execute this on page load and won't wait for my click.
Does anyone know of a way to solve this?

- I tried load a new .cshtml into an invisible div via javascript, but that didn't work.
- This is not an MVC application.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mix server-side code with Javascript.
That won't work.

You need to make the link point to a different server-side page that executes your code.
Alternatively, you could use Javascript to send an AJAX request to a different server-side page that executes your code.

Comment: What I did try already was to make a click event in javascript that would use the jQuery .load() to load another .cshtml page that would then execute the code. That didn't work though. Maybe I'll go with something along the lines of what you suggest. I'll be back when I've tried that. Thanks for your input.

Comment: It may have been a programming error on my part.
Anyways, I used your suggestions and made an ajax request to a webservice I just wrote for the cause and now I have achieved my goal. I'm not sure why I didn't already try this, but thanks for pushing me in the right direction!